# Trouble understanding an exercise given the two's complement in hex format to convert into decimal format

Tags: binary, decimal, hex, twos-complement

I am trying to convert the two's complement of the following hex values to their decimal values:

23, 57, 94 and 87.

a) 23

Procedure: (3 x 16^0) + (2 x 16^1) -> (3) + (32) = 35 (Correct)

b) 57

Procedure: (7 x 16^0) + (5 x 16^1) -> (7) + (80) = 87 (Correct)

For 94 and 87, the correct values are -108 & -121 respectively.

If I follow the procedure I used for numbers a) and b) I get 148 & 128 for 94 & 87.

Can someone explain to me how do I get to the correct results since mine are wrong? Do I need to convert the byte to binary first and then proceed from there?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x94 = 0b10010100

now you can convert it to a decimal number like it is an normal binary number, except that the MSB counts negative:

```
1 * -2^7 + 0 * 2^6 + 0 * 2^5 + 1 * 2^4 + 0 * 2^3 + 1 * 2^2 + 0 * 2^1 + 0 * 2^0 =
-2^7 + 2^4 + 2^2 =
-128 + 16 + 4 =
-108
```

the other number works similar

Answer (score 0):

First write down the binary representation of the hex value:

94h = 10010100b

To take the two's complement, you flip all bits and add 00000001b, so the two's complement of this binary string is

01101011b + 00000001b = 01101100b

Then the first bit is interpreted as the sign (in this case minus), and the remaining 7 bits constitute the magnitude, so:

01101100b = -108d

The other works similarly.